# How to update data on button click

Tags: react-native

```
data:{
    productId: string;
    Name: string;
    Size: [{
         id: string;
         Name: string;
         grade: [{
              Id: string;
              Name: string;
              unitName: string;
              Price: string;

        }
        {
              Id: string;
              Name: string;
              unitName: string;
              Price: string;
         }]
  }]
}
```

I am getting the above response, i have a function in which there is a button and using Flatlist I am rendering this function, now when I click on grade button i want to update the unitName and Price data according to that grade and when I click on size button i want to show only those grade which belongs to that size, please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So If you could just share the code it would be much better but know that you can use `useState` to show a modal like and change the data with the `onChange` method

Comment: I am using Text to show price and unitName so onChange will not work on Text